# How to add an ALL category as the default in select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Category` and `Foo` models that have `has_many/belongs_to` association. In the `new` form, the user has to select a category (e.g. Restaurant, Bar) so that means that each `foo` created belongs to either Restaurant or Bar category.

Now in the `index` page, I have a `select_tag` so the user can filter either by Restaurant or Bar.

```
<%= form_tag foos_path, method: :get, id: "search" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= select_tag :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), class: "category-dropdown" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
    <%= button_tag class: "btn search-btn" do %>
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I add an `ALL` category which will be the default selected?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%= select_tag :category_id, [['ALL','all']]+ options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), class: "category-dropdown" %>
```

you may need to write some condition in controller if params[:category_id] == 'all'

Answer (score 0):

write in your controller action

```
@categories = Category.all
```

than

```
 <%= collection_select(:category_id, @categories, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Prompt <%= select_tag :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name),:prompt => "All Categories", class: "category-dropdown" %>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) While this might answer the question, it's best to also explain *why* it works, so people reading it can understand why they would use your answer.

Comment: No, that's not the solution I wanted.